# Enviar e-mail com conteúdo dinâmico em PHP

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Tenho um template `.html` de e-mail com +- 700 linhas (criado no [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/)) e preciso inserir alguns valores recuperados do banco de dados nele (algo parecido com o que o [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html) faz) antes de enviar para o cliente.

Embora eu não precise inserir tantos dados dinâmicos assim, procuro alguma solução de como fazer isso sem ter que definir o conteúdo no php (a string seria imensa e tomaria muitas linhas de minha classe), estou utilizando o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Segue um exemplo do que desejo fazer, no caso coloquei algumas tags {VAR} pra identificar onde e como desejo alterar o valor do html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Ol&aacute;, {USER}.</p>
        <a href="www.dominio.com/validate/{VALIDATE_KEY}" target="_blank">Clique aqui para ativar sua conta.</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode substituir palavras chave do seu template de maneira simples, usando algo desse tipo:

```
<?php
   //Aqui você define as variáveis na lógica do seu script
   $nome = "Joaquim Augusto";
   $quantidade = "100";

   // Abre o template...
   $corpoDoEmail = file_get_contents('template.txt');

   //E troca as variáveis
   $corpoDoEmail = str_replace( '%NOME%', $nome,       $corpoDoEmail );
   $corpoDoEmail = str_replace( '%QTD%',  $quantidade, $corpoDoEmail );
?>
```

Para HTML, talvez você prefira uma proteção extra com `htmlentities`:

```
$corpoDoEmail = str_replace( '%NOME%', htmlentities( $nome ), $corpoDoEmail );
```

O template.txt seria algo assim:

```
<p>Olá, %NOME%!</p>

<p>Você acaba de ganhar %QTD% pontos de reputação!</p>
```

Em resumo, bastaria editar seu template e definir símbolos especiais para evitar conflitos com outras partes do texto.

Note que o `%` eu escolhi como exemplo, nada impede de você inventar como quiser, desde que não haja perigo de coincidir com texto que não deve ser alterado.

Por exemplo, se fosse um template pra Orkut :P

```
Olá, ^_NomeDoMiguxo_^, ...

$corpoDoEmail = str_replace( '^_NomeDoMiguxo_^', $nome      , $corpoDoEmail );
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é a alternativa mais bonita, mas pode ser usado:

```
<?php

$nome = "Joaquim Augusto";
$validateKey = "auihr43qorehq3brhuq3dfiqawndi==";


$str = <<<EOF
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Ol&aacute;, $nome.</p>
        <a href="www.dominio.com/validate/{$validateKey}" target="_blank">Clique aqui para ativar sua conta.</a>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

O próprio [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) já vem com esta funcionalidade, se chama Merge Vars. ([Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) usa [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/) como delivery de emails)

Merge vars estão disponíveis através de [API](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/merge-vars.php) ou SMTP Headers.

Exemplo de email:

```
Dear *|FNAME|*,
    Thank you for your purchase on *|ORDERDATE|* from ABC Widget Company. 
We appreciate your business and have included a copy of your invoice below.

*|INVOICEDETAILS|*

Please let us know if you have further questions.

     -- ABC Widget Co.
```

SMTP Header:

```
X-MC-MergeVars: {"_rcpt": "emailadress@domain.com", "orderdate": "01/12/2015", "fname":"Nome da criatura"}
```

Fonte:

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-using-smtp-headers-to-customize-your-messages