# Como alterar uma linha especifica de um arquivo em php

Tags: php

Eu tenho um arquivo de configuração, e gostaria de edita-lo por meio de uma pagina em php ao inves de ir manualmente pelo arquivo dele, segue abaixo o exemplo.

```
$db['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['port'] = '3306';
$db['user'] = "root";
$db['pass'] = 'root';
$db['db'] = "database";
```

Comment: O que tentou e qual a dificuldade encontrada? Precisa mais detalhes, pois se for só a geração de um config texto, tem alguns posts no site que já tem exemplos; por outro lado se o config tiver mais do que meras variávels, precisa fazer um parse dele. Se é um modelo padrão, pode usar placeholders, tendo o modelo original com algo como `$db['host'] = "$HOST$"` e trocando as palavras chave por valor (e isso tambem tem resposta no site). Sem dar mais detalhes, dificil definir qual caminho é melhor pro seu caso. Seria bom [edit] e descrever o cenário um pouco melhor esclarecendo essas questões

Comment: Tentei usar fwrite mas ele recria todo arquivo, e meu arquivo de configuração não serão apenas essas 5 linhas terá mais coisas. esse exemplo que você deu sobre trocar a palavra chave $db['host'] = "$HOST$" procurei aqui no site e não achei. Teria algum link do tópico ?

Comment: Esse é um exemplo (tem outros): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54289/70 - note que eu respondi usando um .txt como referencia, mas vc pode salvar com a extensão que quiser. Fazendo desta forma, você mantém os modelos com várias $STRINGS$ como marcação, e troca pelo que quiser.

Comment: Basicamente você lê o texto original numa string e troca com: `$configuracao = str_replace( '%PALAVRA%',  $palavra, $configuracao );`,

Comment: Outros exemplos:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97733/70 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116791/70