# Mudar determinada linha de um arquivo com PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou escrevendo uma aplicação para mudar uma determinada linha em um arquivo HTML. Já consegui localizar a palavra que quero substituir, mas para isso, preciso do número da linha para escrever o novo conteúdo.

```
function changeLine(){
    $file = fopen('index.html', 'r+');

     while(!feof($file)) {
         $conteudo = fgets($file);

          if($resultado = preg_match("/<form/", $conteudo)) {
              echo "Achamos!";
          }
     }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível capturar a linha do arquivo HTML que possui a palavra '<'form.

Comment: Em vez de achar a linha não seria melhor fazer um replace no que vc quer mudar? Vc lê o arquivo e guarda numa variável, faz o replace e grava novamente o arquivo.

Comment: Pode ser também! Estava tentado achar um jeito para fazer isso, teria que fazer a mudança utilizando o fwrite certo?

Comment: Creio que sim...

Comment: Já perguntado aqui: [Como alterar uma linha especifica de um arquivo em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316087/70) - Nos comentários praticamente já tem a solução (basta um mero replace).

Comment: Brigadão! Vou dar uma olhada :)

Answer (score -1):

Consegui mudar a linha dessa maneira. No caso era uma linha bem específica mesmo.

```
<?php
         $url = file_get_contents('index.html');
         $var1 = explode("<form", $url);
         $string = array();

         for($i = 0; $i < 81; $i++) {
            $string[0][$i] = $var1[2][$i];
         }

        saveFileOnce();

        foreach($string as $valor => $detalhes) {
            echo $valor;
            foreach($detalhes as $detalhes => $saida) { 
                saveFile($saida);
            }
        }

        $display = changeMethod();
        echo $display;

        // Salva o conteúdo da linha encontrada em um arquivo separado para ser editado.
        function saveFile($texto) {
            $file = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'a');
            fwrite($file, $texto);
            fclose($file);
        }

        function saveFileOnce() {
            $file = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'a');
            fwrite($file, "<");
            fwrite($file, "form");
            fclose($file);
        }

        function changeMethod(){
            $file = file_get_contents('index.html');
            $contents = file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');
            $change = str_replace($contents, "nova linha", $file);
            return $change;
        }

    ?>
```